# Searching between min and max

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have the following database table

```
id     min     max
1        0       0
2        1      90
3       91     180
4      181     365
5      366       0
```

So, what I need it to happen is this;

If I search for `0`, I should get `id=1 (min=0, max=0);` if I search for `95`, I should get `id=3 (min=91, max=180);` and for anything `>=366`, I should get `id=5;`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @Table 
WHERE   (@Value BETWEEN [MIN] AND [MAX])
OR      (@Value >= [MIN] AND [MAX] = 0)
```

Where @Value is the value you are looking for.

Please note however that more than 1 row might be returned if your [MIN],[MAX] ranges are not unique.

Comment: @Rabin, saw that, and fixed it X-)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for some data.  Thank you for helping.  I've found my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
declare @Search_val int=95;


SELECT  Id
FROM   your_table
WHERE   @Search_val between [min]     and [max]
OR      (@Search_val>min and [max]=0 and [min]!=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  [Id]
FROM    @Table 
WHERE   (@Value BETWEEN [min] AND [max])
OR      (@Value >= [min] AND [max] = -1)
```

Is it possible to make the max of the infinite number (ID 5's max) to -1?

if so the above code will work great.

You need a unique way to say that any number higher than the min must be included, and using 0 on both id 1 and 5 isnt unique
.

EDIT --> this should work if you can't change to -1

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Id]
FROM    @Table 
WHERE   (@Value BETWEEN [min] AND [max])
OR      (@Value >= [min] AND [max] = 0)
ORDER BY [MIN] DESC
```

Comment: Have a look at the edit I added, I could clean it up a bit, but I am sure you can see what is happening, and change it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @Value INT = 400

SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE (@Value >= 366 AND Min = 366 ) 
OR @Value BETWEEN Min AND MAX
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is what happens if those values change?  then you need to adjust the query, where as my solution(below my initial solution) doesn't use any hard coded values.  So the question is, will those values change ever? or are they static?

Comment: I see what you mean @Johan.  The ceiling value of 366 haven't changed in quite of lot of years and I don't anticipate it to change in the near future.  You have given me food for thoughts.  Thank you.